# Troubleshooting 'extraGeneratedResDir' error while using Firebase with Flutter on Android

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

Installed Firebase CLI run Every Step that is defined correctly now got this error in my flutter project.

> Error while evaluating property 'extraGeneratedResDir' of task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths' property 'extraGeneratedResDir'.
> > Querying the mapped value of provider(java.util.Set) before task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' has completed is not supported

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)